# My "test if this is a prime number" code crashes when I test numbers greater than 4

Tags: python, primes

I'm a Python noobie, please have mercy.

I tried to create a code to test if a given number is a prime number. I tried the %, sqrt, and n methods. All ended with the same result: when I try to test the code for numbers greater than 4, the code returns NULL and says "Process finished with exit code 0"

Can you please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code I wrote (this is the 'n' method where I apply % to numbers all the way up to n; I know it's not the most efficient, but I'll fix that after I make sure it works):

```
x = 5
if x > 1:
    for i in range(2, x):
        if (x % i) == 0:
            print("NOT prime")
        break
    else:
        print("YES, it's prime")
else:
    print("NOT prime, because the number is < 1")
```

Comment: Note: To test primes you only need to go up to `int(math.sqrt(x))`.

Comment: You always `break` on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: try indenting your `break`

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your help, I really appreciate it. Indeed, it was the break that needed indenting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

break should be indented once more, so it does not break the loop when it is not a prime.

Comment: It's usually not worth answering questions that are due to typos, because they get closed and deleted pretty quickly. See [Answer]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!